# Query returns duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query to get the size of tables in all databases.

```
DECLARE @DBName varchar(200)
DECLARE @CMD varchar(max)
DECLARE @TV TABLE ( name_table varchar(500),ROWSCOUNT int, reserveder varchar(50), datasize varchar(50), indexsize varchar(50), unused varchar(50))
declare @tv2 table ( DBName varchar(200),name_table varchar(500),ROWSCOUNT int, reserved varchar(50), datasize float, indexsize varchar(50), unused varchar(50))
DECLARE @TV3 TABLE ( DBName varchar(200),SchemaTAble varchar(500), TableName varchar(200))
DECLARE C Cursor for select quotename(name) as dbname from sys.databases where name <> 'tempdb'  and state = 0

OPEN C

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @TV3
    SET @CMD = 
    @DBName+'..sp_MSforeachtable ''exec sp_spaceused [?]'''
    insert into @TV
    EXEC (@CMD)

    SET @CMD = 'select '''+@DBName+''' as DatabaseName, quotename(s.name)+''.''+quotename(t.name) as SchemaTable, quotename(t.name) TableName from '+@DBName+'.sys.tables t inner join '+@DBName+'.sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id '
    insert into @TV3
    EXEC (@CMD)

    insert into @TV2
    select @DBName ,t.name_table,t.ROWSCOUNT,round(cast(replace(t.reserveder,' kb','')as float)/1024,2),round(cast(replace(t.datasize,' kb','') as float)/1024,2),t.indexsize,t.unused from @TV t
    inner join @TV3 s on quotename(t.name_table) = s.TableName and s.DBName = @DBName

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @DBNAME
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCate C

select   DBname+','+cast(datasize as varchar(20))+','+cast(round(cast(replace(IndexSize,' kb','')as float)/1024,2)as varchar(20))+','+cast(round(cast(replace(unused,' kb','')as float)/1024,2)as varchar(20))+','+name_table +','+cast(reserved as varchar(20))+','+'mssql'+','+cast(ROWSCOUNT as varchar(20))+','+cast(current_timestamp as varchar(20)) from @TV2 order by  datasize desc
```

But the query returns duplicate records in my production server.

```
 E.g
 [BookingDB],28027.7,4565.87,0,booking_details,32591.1,mssql,118800560,Feb
 28 2017 12:29PM
[BookingDB_Lo],28027.7,4565.87,0,booking_details,32591.1,mssql,118800560,Feb
 28 2017 12:29PM
[BookingDB_FT],28027.7,4565.87,0,booking_details,32591.1,mssql,118800560,Feb
 28 2017 12:29PM
[BookingDB_RC],28027.7,4565.87,0,booking_details,32591.1,mssql,118800560,Feb
 28 2017 12:29PM
```

Here the datas of same tables showing in different databases.Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below query that I wrote and always use to check the space used of all tables on all databases (except TempDB) has not failed me yet.

```
create table ##SpaceUsed
(
    [DatabaseName]  varchar(100),
    [TableName]     varchar(100),
    [RowCount]      bigint,
    [ReservedSpace] bigint,
    [DataSize]      bigint,
    [IndexSize]     bigint,
    [UnusedSpace]   bigint
)

declare @Databases as table
(
    RecordID        int IDENTITY(1,1),
    DatabaseName    varchar(100)
)

insert into @Databases(DatabaseName)
select
    Name
from
    sys.databases
where
    Name <> 'tempdb'

declare @DatabaseName           varchar(100)
declare @SQL                    varchar(MAX)
declare @CurrentDatabaseRow     int
declare @MaxDatabaseRow         int

set @CurrentDatabaseRow = (select MIN(RecordID) from @Databases)
set @MaxDatabaseRow = (select MAX(RecordID) from @Databases)

while @CurrentDatabaseRow <= @MaxDatabaseRow
begin
    set @DatabaseName = (select DatabaseName from @Databases where RecordID = @CurrentDatabaseRow)

    set @SQL = '

                        USE ['+@DatabaseName+']

                        declare @SpaceUsedTemp as table
                        (
                            [TableName]     varchar(100),
                            [RowCount]      varchar(100),
                            [ReservedSpace] varchar(100),
                            [DataSize]      varchar(100),
                            [IndexSize]     varchar(100),
                            [UnusedSpace]   varchar(100)
                        )

                        declare @Tables as table
                        (
                            RecordID    int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            SchemaName  varchar(200),
                            TableName   varchar(200)
                        )

                        -------------------------------------------------------------------
                        ---------------------Filter to user tables only--------------------
                        -------------------------------------------------------------------

                        Insert into @Tables(SchemaName, TableName)
                        select
                            s.[name],
                            t.[Name]
                        from
                            sys.tables t
                        inner join
                            sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                        --where t.type = ''U''

                        -------------------------------------------------------------------
                        -------------------------------------------------------------------

                        declare @SchemaName     varchar(200)
                        declare @TableName      varchar(200)
                        declare @FullObjectName varchar(400)
                        declare @CurrentRow     int
                        declare @MaxRow         int

                        set @CurrentRow = (select MIN(RecordID) from @Tables)
                        set @MaxRow = (select MAX(RecordID) from @Tables)

                        while @CurrentRow <= @MaxRow
                        begin
                            set @SchemaName = (select SchemaName from @Tables where RecordID = @CurrentRow)
                            set @TableName = (select TableName from @Tables where RecordID = @CurrentRow)
                            set @FullObjectName = @SchemaName + ''.'' + @TableName

                            Insert into @SpaceUsedTemp(TableName, [RowCount], [ReservedSpace], [DataSize], [IndexSize], [UnusedSpace])
                            exec sp_spaceused @FullObjectName

                            set @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1
                        end

                        insert into ##SpaceUsed
                        select 
                            '''+@DatabaseName+''',
                            [TableName],
                            convert(int, REPLACE([RowCount], '' KB'', ''''))        ,
                            convert(int, REPLACE([ReservedSpace], '' KB'', ''''))   ,
                            convert(int, REPLACE([DataSize], '' KB'', ''''))        ,
                            convert(int, REPLACE([IndexSize], '' KB'', ''''))       ,
                            convert(int, REPLACE([UnusedSpace], '' KB'', '''')) 
                        from 
                            @SpaceUsedTemp


    '

    exec (@SQL)

    set @CurrentDatabaseRow = @CurrentDatabaseRow + 1
end

select * from ##SpaceUsed
order by DatabaseName, TableName

drop table ##SpaceUsed


/*
          __  __                                             
         |. ||. |    .|                                      
         || ||| |    | |                             
         |: ||: |    |'|                   ._____    
         |  ||  |   |  |     .--'|  .---"| |.   |'   
     _   |  ||  |-. |  | __  |.  | _|__  | ||   |__  
  .-'|  _|  ||  | ||   '-  | ||   |   |' | |    | |' 
  |' | |.|  ||  | ||       '-'    |   |  | |    | |  
__|  '-' '  ''  ' ""       '      `   -  |_'    ' |__

______________________________________________________

                  Joachim J Prinsloo
               http://jjprinsloo.co.za
______________________________________________________

*/
```

If you want to only view user tables, change the following code:

```
Insert into @Tables(SchemaName, TableName)
select
    s.[name],
    t.[Name]
from
    sys.tables t
inner join
    sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
```

to this:

```
Insert into @Tables(SchemaName, TableName)
select
    s.[name],
    t.[Name]
from
    sys.tables t
inner join
    sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where t.type = ''U'' --WHERE CLAUSE ADDED TO SHOW ONLY USER TABLES
```

You can find the location of where to add the where clause in the code section marked with the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------Filter to user tables only--------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can just uncomment the where clause line and it will be filtered.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It returns the below error."The object 'ScrapReason' does not exist in database 'AdventureWorks2012' or is invalid for this operation".

Comment: Like this for all tables

Comment: @SujithTee, Thats quite wierd. I have never tested on AdventureWorks. I don't like that my query is returning errors. Downloading AdventureWorks now. I'll test and see what the problem is.

Comment: Ok @Joachim go ahead.

Comment: @SujithTee, The problem was that the script did not take the table schema into considderation. As AdventureWorks is a multi-schema database it failed because it was looking for the 'ScrapReason' table on the 'dbo' schema when it is in fact on the 'Production' schema. I have modified the script to take the schema into consideration and updated the code in the answer. It should work on AdventureWorks now.

Comment: Thanks Joachim.Kindly alter your query to get only user tables.Please omit system databases.

Comment: @SujithTee, I don't want to do that on the Stack Overflow query. As the next person who comes along might want to see system tables as well. If you want to omit the system tables though, you can add a where clause to the table selection part: where t.type = ''U''. I have edited the query to reflect this.

Comment: @SujithTee, I have updated the question as reference. You will notice what to change to filter for user tables only.

Comment: @SujithTee, Please be sure to mark as answer if the script helped you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not returning duplicated rows.

I've checked it on one of my test servers:

```
[test],0.01,0.01,0,tt,0.02,mssql,4,Feb 28 2017  9:56AM
[test],0.01,0.02,0,btree,0.03,mssql,14,Feb 28 2017  9:56AM
[test],0,0,0,ueExpedicions,0,mssql,0,Feb 28 2017  9:56AM
[test],0,0,0,ueExpReferencies,0,mssql,0,Feb 28 2017  9:56AM
[test],0,0,0,ueContainers,0,mssql,0,Feb 28 2017  9:56AM
[test],0,0,0,t_albarans_remeses,0,mssql,0,Feb 28 2017  9:56AM
[test],0,0,0,tlbCalendar,0,mssql,0,Feb 28 2017  9:56AM
[test],0,0,0,luCalendarType,0,mssql,0,Feb 28 2017  9:56AM
```

If you take a look at your results:

```
[BookingDB],28027.7,4565.87,0,booking_details,32591.1,mssql,118800560,Feb 28 2017 12:29PM
[BookingDB_Lo],28027.7,4565.87,0,booking_details,32591.1,mssql,118800560,Feb 28 2017 12:29PM
[BookingDB_FT],28027.7,4565.87,0,booking_details,32591.1,mssql,118800560,Feb 28 2017 12:29PM
[BookingDB_RC],28027.7,4565.87,0,booking_details,32591.1,mssql,118800560,Feb 28 2017 12:29PM
```

I spouse you are using partitioned tables.

There is an answer on this post about how to deal with it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36612128/3270427

Comment: No @McNets.I have tested in production server.They are duplicates only.

Comment: yeah..I have same tables in all databases..But the sizes are totally different.

Comment: Their sizes are small.So the displaying in the down.and for that tables also dispalaying in all databases

Comment: NO.this did not works

Comment: are your working with partitioned tables?